# How to add object as properties to array

Tags: javascript

I get the following array from CSVparse function. I am trying to get my data directly from JSON without creating a csv file.

```
DATA (2) [{…}, {…}, columns: Array(4)]
0: {date: '2022-11-08 04:00:00', Ballon: '0.58', DepartPAC: '23.32', RetourPAC: '21.94'}
1: {date: '2022-11-08 04:01:00', Ballon: '0.59', DepartPAC: '23.98', RetourPAC: '21.58'}
columns: (4) ['date', 'Ballon', 'DepartPAC', 'RetourPAC']
```

So now I don't understand how I can add the following property Colonne to my array:

```
const Colonne = ['date', 'Ballon', 'DépartPAC', 'RetourPAC'];
```

As what I have tried is given an automatic index and I would like to have the string columns as an index (I know that index can be only numbers but it seems possible) as this is not added as an index but as a property.
I get following result:

```
(2) [Array(77), {…}]
0:(77) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1:{id: 'columns', values: Array(4)}
```

using this code:

```
 retour.push({columns:Colonne});
//or
retour.splice("Columns", 0, Colonne);
```

I am getting my data with AJAX:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'DonneesGraph.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( retour ) {
            // Ici le traitement des données retournées placé dans quelquechose=JSON ? appelé retour 
            
            console.log( "Retour" , retour );
```

Then I get the name of columns and can build my object columns:

```
const Lenght =Object.keys(retour[0]).length;
const Nom=Object.keys(retour[0]);
console.log("Nombre de colonnes",Lenght);
console.log("Nom",Nom[2]);
const Colonne = ['date', 'Ballon', 'DépartPAC', 'RetourPAC'];
```

So the goal is to get this object columns into my array same as this:

```
DATA (2) [{…}, {…}, columns: Array(4)]
0: {date: '2022-11-08 04:00:00', Ballon: '0.58', DepartPAC: '23.32', RetourPAC: '21.94'}
1: {date: '2022-11-08 04:01:00', Ballon: '0.59', DepartPAC: '23.98', RetourPAC: '21.58'}
columns: (4) ['date', 'Ballon', 'DepartPAC', 'RetourPAC']
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what's the goal here, what you tried. If you could post your current data and expected data examples that'd be helpful. I don't understand what *add the following code to my array* means.

Comment: I dont understand it either

Comment: You can add `array.columns = ['date', 'Ballon', 'DépartPAC', 'RetourPAC']`. It will add a property to the array object. But, you can't add this property to JSON. That's not valid. You'd have to use an object: `{ "0": { }, "1": { }, "columns": [] }`

Comment: Or, if you just want to get the keys of the objects, then use `Object.keys(array[0])`

Comment: @adiga Hi yes i think you get my point. I am a little confuse about managing this. So i get my array from AJAX, then i can store it with JS with a name and then how to add the object as you write : { "0": { }, "1": { }, "columns": [] } ?

Comment: If all the objects of the array have the same key names, you don't have to send the column names form the server. You could send the JSON `[{ "date": "2022-11-08', "Ballon": "0.58"... }, {..}]` from the server side and get the key names of the first object in the array: `Object.keys(array[0])`

Comment: @adiga ok i get more or less this point, i just need to build the array with this specific propertie because this is treated somehow later in the programm with a specific librarie from 3DJS. I have edited my post to clarify more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to achieve something like this.

```
{
  date: [ '2022-11-08 04:00:00', '2022-11-08 04:01:00' ],
  Ballon: [ '0.58', '0.59' ],
  DepartPAC: [ '23.32', '23.98' ],
  RetourPAC: [ '21.94', '21.58' ]
}
```

Here's the code for that.

```
let data = [
    {
        date: '2022-11-08 04:00:00', 
        Ballon: '0.58', 
        DepartPAC: '23.32', 
        RetourPAC: '21.94'
    }, 
    {
        date: '2022-11-08 04:01:00', 
        Ballon: '0.59', 
        DepartPAC: '23.98', 
        RetourPAC: '21.58'
    }];

function getColumnWiseData(data) {
    let columnWiseData = {};
    let columns = Object.keys(data[0]);
    columns.forEach((column) => {
        columnWiseData[column] = [];
    });
    data.forEach((row) => {
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            columnWiseData[column].push(row[column]);
        });
    });
    return columnWiseData;
}

console.log(getColumnWiseData(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes this is part of the process, but i suceed to get this. As mentionned i need same structure as original one because after the data are used by specific librarie of 3DJS

Comment: I found, was spending so much time with this. I just need to write it ````retour['columns']=[Nom[0], Nom[1], Nom[2], Nom[3]];//WORKS````